# Understanding 0-spheres.

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition**: a $0-$sphere is a pair of points {c − r, c + r}, and is the boundary of a line segment (1-ball).

In my notes is written that $\{0\}$ is open and close in a $0-$sphere. Why?

*For me that it haven't sense because a $0-$sphere is two points.*

Is all point in a  $0-$sphere open and close? why?

Comment: Take a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of finitely many points. Then every point of $S$ is both open and closed in $S$. This comes from the definition of [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). (Actually, it isn't even necessary that $S$ is finite, as long as it does not contain accumulation points).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topology on the $(n-1)$-sphere is inhereted from the topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or equivalently from the topology on the $n$-ball.

In this case, the topology on the $0$-sphere $\{c-r,c+r\}$ is inhereted from the topology on $\mathbb{R}$. So it's a pair of points $c-r, c+r$, and both points are both open and closed.
So yes, every subset of a $0$-sphere is open and closed.

When you say $\{0\}$ is open and closed, this only makes sense if $c-r = 0$ or $c + r = 0$. But if so, then it is true, by the above reasoning.